# Get array/object value by referencing the object and key as string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of an array/object by passing KEY that is splitted from data attribute.

Please take a look of this whole scenario.

1st - passing the `data-*` to an element

```
 <a data-action='{"content":"content.login"}' ... >val</a>
```

2nd - get the data attribute value

```
 var da = ele.data("action");
 var c = da.content;
 var c0 = c.split('.')[0];
 var c1 = c.split('.')[1];
```

4th - array/obj

```
 var content = {
    login : "..."
 };
```

3rd - trying to get the `val` of array

```
 console.log(c0[c1]);
```

result - `undefined`

Can someone give me the solution so that it logs the exact value of `content.login` by simply calling `c0[c1]`?

Comment: `c0` suposed to be a string like `"content"`, right? So this can't work `c0[c1]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the variable using the string by passing it to window: `window[c0][c1]`

```js
var content = {
   login : "awesome"
};

var data = $('div').data('data');
var c = data.content;

var c0 = c.split('.')[0];
var c1 = c.split('.')[1];

console.log(c0, c1);

alert(window[c0][c1]); 
   // translates to window['content']['login'] => calls content.login
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-data='{"content":"content.login"}'></div>
```

NOTE: If you are in a function closure you can use `this` instead of `window`.

Comment: its working great. But please can u explain the concept behind `window`.

Comment: Window is an object that contains DOM elements, functions/methods, events and the variables you create. It's basically the parent of everything.  [You can find what it has here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window)

Comment: When you for example call the variable `c` the you are actually calling `window.c` but the window part is not mandatory anymore since it's build in with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing assignment of a single element rather than of array:

```
var c0 = c.split('.')[0]; //Take 1st element of array
```

So you can't try to access element of array like you have:

```
c0[c1]
```

Just print c0.